# ZXing.Net 0.16.8 BarcodeReader<Bitmap> and BitmapLuminanceSource initialisation

Tags: c#, barcode, zxing

I'm using C# .Net6, and ZXing.Net 0.16.8 to try and read a barcode, but I'm having trouble initialising the "reader".

The following don't work, or give me null results:

`BarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();`

`BarcodeReaderGeneric reader = new BarcodeReaderGeneric();`

Later I found ZXing.Net 0.16.8 requires the reader to be initialised as:

`BarcodeReader<Bitmap> reader;`

Now this is where I struggle. That reader cannot be null before use, but I don't know how to initialise it.
It seems it needs to be initialised with a function.

`BarcodeReader<Bitmap> reader = new BarcodeReader<Bitmap>(what do I put in here?);`

It seems it needs to in a format such as `Func<Bitmap, LuminanceSource>`, but I have no clue how to do this.
I believe I will also get stuck initialising the LuminanceSource.

Hopefully, initialising the reader as `BarcodeReader<Bitmap>` will return something other than null.

Comment: The first half of your question is confusing. Neither `BarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader()` nor `BarcodeReaderGeneric reader = new BarcodeReaderGeneric()` will give null result. In both cases, the code is either not compilable when there is no parameterless constructor for the _BarcodeReader_ and _BarcodeReaderGeneric_ classes, or it will absolutely create an instance of these classes. In other words, the _reader_ variable will always be non-null upon execution of these lines.

Comment: I just need to find a way of completing BarcodeReader<Bitmap> reader = new BarcodeReader<Bitmap>(this bit here between parenthesis);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main ZXing.Net nuget package for .net 6 doesn't contain a specific barcode reader implementation for the Bitmap class or something else.
You have to add one of the ZXing.Net binding packages which fit your needs. That means you should select one of them for your preferred image manipulation library:
https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=ZXing.Net.Bindings
In your case, I think, would be the following the best choice:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net.Bindings.Windows.Compatibility
Then you can initialize your reader instance with the following snippet:

```
var reader = new ZXing.Windows.Compatibility.BarcodeReader();
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, the Compatibility package did the trick and I can now read barcodes. :D